# Hystrix fallback handling 2 dbcall

Tags: hystrix

Hystrix fallback issue.
If dbcall1 goes in fallback due to some failure and short-circuit happens, then dbcall2 also goes in fallback evrytime untill the circuit opens.

```
   public class CommandHelloFailure extends HystrixCommand<String> {

    private final String name;

    public CommandHelloFailure(String name) {
        super(HystrixCommandGroupKey.Factory.asKey("ExampleGroup"));
        this.name = name;
    }`enter code here`
String dbcall1 ()
{
new CommandHelloFailure().execute();
}
String dbcall2()
{
new CommandHelloFailure().execute();
}
    @Override
    protected String run() {
        throw new RuntimeException("this command always fails");
    }

    @Override
    protected String getFallback() {
        return "Hello Failure " + name + "!";
    }
}
```

However i want independent fallback for both the method(DB call).

Comment: Your code does not compile. Please edit and fix

Comment: its the pseudo code.. the issue i am facing is 1) if dbcall1() goes to fallback due to actual failure and short-circuit happens, thn for withCircuitBreakerSleepWindowInMilliseconds time, both the call(dbcall1() and dbcall2()) goes in fallback.  @rjdkolb

Answer (score 0):

That's because you didn't specify `HystrixCommandKey`. If you doesn't specify `HystrixCommandKey`, `HystrixCommandKey` is derived from the class name. Namely CommandHelloFailure will be used as `HystrixCommandKey`.

It means that `dbcall1` and `dbcall2` will share the same circuit breaker.
Because Circuit Break is created for each `HystrixCommandKey`, not `HystrixCommandGroupKey`.